# List.js not sorting very long items properly

Tags: javascript, listjs

I’ve been using List.js for a few months and it’s been working great. My project only has 16 or so items in my list but it seems my items have many characters. It seems that List.js stops counting after a certain character limit but I can’t find any documentation of that or workaround. Please see my example:

```js
var monkeyList = new List('test-list', { 
  valueNames: ['name'], 
  plugins: [ ListFuzzySearch() ] 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js"></script>
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.fuzzysearch.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="test-list">
    <input type="text" class="fuzzy-search" />
    <ul class="list">
      <li><p class="name">Guybrush Threepwood</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Elaine Marley</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">LeChuck</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Stan</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Voodoo Lady</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Herman Toothrot</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Meathook</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Carla</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Otis</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Rapp Scallion</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Rum Rogers Sr.</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Men of Low Moral Fiber fissure caries cavities prevention preventive preventative pits pedo pediatrics sizzurp</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Murray</p></li>
      <li><p class="name">Cannibals</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

So for example if you search for “cavities” you get a result as expected but not “sizzurp”

Any ideas how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to set the options of the fuzzysearch plugin.

```
var fuzzyOptions = {
  searchClass: "fuzzy-search",
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  threshold: 0.4,
  multiSearch: true
};
```

Look at the [FuzzySearch documentation](http://www.listjs.com/docs/plugins/fuzzysearch). The variables are explained.
Probably you have to set the "distance" to another range. ("sizzurp" is starting at position 104 - so maybe `distance:200` would be great).